# Is it possible to make a contenteditable paragraph focused with a button?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a contenteditable paragraph focused with a button.

I've tried making the paragraph focused (like you would with an input), but it doesn't work. Like this:

```
document.getElementById("example").focus();
```

This is an example of what it should look like (I used input for this example):
https://jsfiddle.net/7rwft2c3/

Comment: Why don't you use input with no border? Then, you can focus the input, and it would look like a paragraph.

Comment: Please see me edited answer. It more directly answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you would like to focus must be editable first. According to the spec, you can only `.focus()` on a focusable area.

The spec says:

> The term **focusable area** is used to refer to regions of the interface
>   that can become the target of keyboard input.

Here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#focusable-area

So add the `contentEditable` attribute first, and then `.focus()` the element.

Per the comment below, `.blur()` is not necessary because once the `contentediable` attribute is removed, the element can no longer be focused.

Note here I changed the `<input>` to a `<div>`:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("myText");

function getFocus() {
  el.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
  el.focus();
}

function loseFocus() {
  el.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
}
```

```html
<div id="myText">A Div</div>

<button type="button" onclick="getFocus()">Get focus</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loseFocus()">Lose focus</button>
```

Comment: You can use `blur` for removing focus on an element

Comment: Sure, but there is no need. When the attribute is removed, so is the focus.